# postfix smtp auth port 25

Tags: authentication, smtp, postfix

I have a working postfix/dovecot at home on a Raspberry Pi.

I have enabled smtps (port 465) and force auth which is working.

**But I still can telnet my server on port 25 and send email without auth to a mailbox of my domain.
Of course I can't telnet/email to another domain ( Error "Relay access denied" )**

It's a normal behaviour but can i fix it ? Of course I need to receive mails from other mail servers on the Internet.

For instance, if you "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25", you can't send an email, you need to auth, how do they do that ?

Thank you

Comment: what is `smtpd_relay_restrictions` set to? Post the output of `postconf smtpd_relay_restrictions`, please.

Comment: smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, I have edited my first comment.  

The "problem" is when sending an email to mailbox of my domain, relay is not working as expected without auth

Comment: Ah okay then I got this wrong. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour. Postfix is accepting all mail to domains it is responsible for, that's it's job. It is what you configured it to do using the `smtpd_relay_restrictions` setting, more precisely via the [`reject_unauth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination) option.

As you said, other mail servers need to be able to deliver mails to you, thus naturally you are able to, too.

The reason you cannot send mail to `smtp.gmail.com` is that they have split mail servers for incoming and outgoing mail. `smtp.gmail.com` is for outgoing mail (that is, mail from one of their clients to whereever - you need to authenticate there. For incoming mail, `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.` is responsible (see `host gmail.com` output). There, you can deliver mail without authentication.

Comment: Okay thanks for your great answer  ! That makes sense.